# How can I parse a JSON object containing a PHP array of objects?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, parsing

I have created an AJAX function that is used with pagination links to load a new page of posts on the fly, and have everything working great except I can't figure out how to parse a JSON object like this one.

This is the style of PHP that is getting passed as JSON:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        ['var1'] => val1
        ['var2'] => var2
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        ['var1'] => val1
        ['var2'] => var2
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        ['var1'] => val1
        ['var2'] => var2
    )
)
```

And is being passed to it with this:

```
$response = json_encode( array( 'success' => true, 'posts' => $new_posts ) );
```

Where `$new_posts` is the array I'm trying to parse.

Can anybody show me how I can access these variables and their values? Thanks.

**Update:** [Here's the JSON string](http://pastebin.com/MJEZsUPL)

I'm trying to access these from JavaScript.

**Update 2:** When I use `var posts = JSON.parse( response.posts );` I get the following error in Google Chrome Javascript Console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

**Update 3:** I just checked Firebug and it only seems to be returning this for the JSON response text:

`{"success":true,"posts":[]}`

Comment: Sooo.... do you feel like showing us the actual JSON?

Comment: Are you trying to access those variables from JavaScript?

Comment: Well the string is over 6500 characters long, so sorry for that! Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, the best approach would be to use the `parseJSON` method:

`var respObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);`

Comment: When I use this, I get the following error in the Google Chrome Javascript console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` - any idea why that would happen?

Comment: It most likely means that there is a un-terminated string in your JSON text. It might due to a string that is incorrectly escaped.

Comment: You were right, I had to double encode it and now I'm able to get the variables in my Javascript code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to access via JavaScript since you have this in PHP. On your XHR success callback, insert the response in a JSON.parse(); and access everything as follows

```
var data = JSON.parse(recievedData); // newer browsers, optionally you can use jQuery or eval()
console.log(data); // test;
// loop through all data
for(var i=0;i<data.length;++i) {
   console.log(data[i].var1); // expects val1
   console.log(data[i].var2); // expects val2
}
//access one bit
console.log(data[0].var1);
```

jQuery response method (there are many ways to achieve this)

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(recievedData)
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is valid javascript, so the most straightforward solution (assuming you trust the source of the json 100%) is to simply eval() it.

```
var response = eval(the_json);

if (response.success){
    var posts = response.posts
}
```

If you're using a library like jQuery, there are built-in methods to more safely evaluate json strings.

Comment: I am using the jQuery library as well, the script is dependent on it. Can you show me how to do it that way?

Comment: You might also want to include a note about the new ECMAScript 5 standard [`window.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON).

Comment: JSON.parse is more correct.  If the JSON is coming from an untrusted source you're evaling their arbitrary javascript.  Even in old versions of IE I used to just go grab the JSON class from json.org for a safer way of doing this.

Comment: Paul Irish also wrote [a post that mentions the way jQuery parses JSON](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/). Very informative.